# TypeError: Expected float32, but got auto of type 'str'. Tensorflow error , tell me how to fix it?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, typeerror, tensorflow2.0

I got ***TypeError: Expected float32, but got auto of type 'str'.*** error while fitting the sequential model.
I checked my inputs both are numpy.ndarray.

```
type(xtrain),type(ytrain)
(numpy.ndarray, numpy.ndarray)

model = tf.keras.Sequential()

model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape = (28,28)))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(32,activation='relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(32,activation='relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(10,activation=tf.keras.activations.softmax))

model.compile(loss = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy,optimizer = 
    tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=.0001),metrics = ['accuracy'])

model.fit(x =xtrain,y = ytrain,epochs=100)

Epoch 1/100
```

---

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
----> 1 model.fit(x =xtrain,y = ytrain,epochs=100)

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py in autograph_handler(*args, **kwargs)
1127           except Exception as e:  # pylint:disable=broad-except
1128             if hasattr(e, "ag_error_metadata"):
-> 1129               raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
1130             else:
1131               raise

TypeError: in user code:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 878, in train_function  *
    return step_function(self, iterator)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 867, in step_function  **
    outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 860, in run_step  **
    outputs = model.train_step(data)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 810, in train_step
    y, y_pred, sample_weight, regularization_losses=self.losses)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/compile_utils.py", line 201, in __call__
    loss_value = loss_obj(y_t, y_p, sample_weight=sw)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/losses.py", line 141, in __call__
    losses = call_fn(y_true, y_pred)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/losses.py", line 245, in call  **
    return ag_fn(y_true, y_pred, **self._fn_kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/losses.py", line 752, in __init__  **
    from_logits=from_logits)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/losses.py", line 227, in __init__
    super().__init__(reduction=reduction, name=name)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/losses.py", line 88, in __init__
    losses_utils.ReductionV2.validate(reduction)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/utils/losses_utils.py", line 82, in validate
    if key not in cls.all():

TypeError: Expected float32, but got auto of type 'str'.
```

Answer (score 2):

The error may be in this part of the code:

```
model.compile(loss = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy,optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=.0001),metrics = ['accuracy'])
```

Try changing the loss parameter from `tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy` to `tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy()`.

For some clarity, the difference between the two is that with `tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy` you are *not* passing and instance of the class, with `tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy()` you are.